# passing data from controller to Type symfony2

Tags: symfony

if i show a field of type "entity" in my form, and i want to filter this entity type based on a argument I pass from the controller, how do i do that.. ?

```
//PlumeOptionsType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('framePlume', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'DessinPlumeBundle:PhysicalPlume',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('pp')
                                    ->where("pp.profile = :profile")
                                    ->orderBy('pp.index', 'ASC')
                                    ->setParameter('profile', ????)
                                ;
                            },

    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'plumeOptions';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
            'data_class'      => 'Dessin\PlumeBundle\Entity\PlumeOptions',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            // a unique key to help generate the secret token
            'intention'       => 'plumeOptions_item',
    );
}
}
```

and inside the controller, i create the form :

```
i have that argument that i need to pass in my action code:
$profile_id = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('profile_id');
...
and then i create my form like this
$form = $this->createForm(new PlumeOptionsType(), $plumeOptions);
```

the $plumeOptions is just a class to persist. But it has a one-to-one relationship with another class called PhysicalPlume. Now, when i want to display the 'framePlume' in my code, i want to show a filtered PhysicalPlume entity.

Comment: answered already...
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the form class as follows:

```
//PlumeOptionsType.php
protected $profile;

public function __construct (Profile $profile)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;
}
```

Then use it in the query_builder of your buildForm:

```
$profile = $this->profile;

$builder->add('framePlume', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'DessinPlumeBundle:PhysicalPlume',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($profile) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('pp')
                                ->where("pp.profile = :profile")
                                ->orderBy('pp.index', 'ASC')
                                ->setParameter('profile', $profile)
                            ;
                        },

));
```

And finally in your controller:

```
// fetch $profile from DB
$form = $this->createForm(new PlumeOptionsType($profile), $plumeOptions);
```

Comment: thx for answering, I think you got exactly what i mean...
Still, i got an error doing exactly what you suggested.
    Using $this when not in object context 
    in PlumeBundle\Form\Type\PlumeOptionsType.php

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RVLFCxL4
http://pastebin.com/778ygFgR
http://pastebin.com/q81k8w9A

I think my problem is related to callback function. i can read the profile from inside PlumeOptionsType, but not from inside 
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)

Comment: :please post that answer again with the "use" statement so we can set this question as answered !!

Comment: Passing a form type is now deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027711/passing-data-to-buildform-in-symfony-2-8-3-0

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$plumeOptions` to pass everything your argument, but you'll need to add a `getDefaultOptions()` in `PlumeOptionsType` to specify the default value for your option.
See for instance https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/CheckboxType.php to see what this method should look like.

Comment: Can you elaborate more.. ?
can you be more specific ??

Comment: I edited my message to add more precisions on the `getDefaultOptions()` method

Comment: Ok, let's say i added a default profile_id in the returned array of getDefaultOptions() of PlumeOptionsType.
and i used 
->setParameter('profile', $options['profile_id'])...

but how to pass profile_id to the $plumeOptions at the first place??
Thank you for your help !!

Comment: ?!? Just do this : `$plumeOptions['profile_id'] = 42`... I think I don't get the real problem.

Comment: i got this now:

    public function editPlumeOptionsAction(Request $request, $user_ou)
    { 
    //get session and get profile_id from session
 
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DessinProfileBundle:Profile');
   
    $profile = $repository->findOneById($profile_id);
  
    $plumeOptions = $profile->getPlumeOptions();
  
    if(!$plumeOptions instanceof PlumeOptions)
      $plumeOptions  = new PlumeOptions();
    $plumeOptions['profile_id'] = $profile_id;
    $form = $this->createForm(new PlumeOptionsType(), $plumeOptions);

i got an error "Cannot use object of type ..."

Comment: i have a table profile 1<->1 relationship with table plumeOptions.
and table PlumeOptions 1<->1 relationship with table PhysicalPlume.
and table Profile has a relationship of 1to200 PhysicalPlume.

so in the table PhysicalPlume, there is a FK profile id.
that's what i want my form to display:
not all PhysicalPlumes, but only the ones related to that profile.
Hope this helps a bit clarifying the picture..

Comment: Please update your answer instead of putting code in comments.

Comment: You get this error because `$plumeOptions` is supposed to be an array. Instead, you provide a `PlumeOptions` object. Too achieve your goald : should use a `CollectionType` type like this : http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/inconsistent-behavior-of-symfony2s-form-framework/ . Have a look to the `newAction()` method to see how objects are added to the collection.