# Symfony: use of query builder in a Form

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I have a form that I am building using the FormBuilder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('rosters',   'entity',   array(
            'class' => 'ReliefAppsPlatformBundle:Roster',
            'property' => 'display',
            'query_builder' => function(RosterRepository $r) use ($user) {
                return $r->createQueryBuilder('r')
                    ->leftJoin('r.members', 'm')
                    ->addSelect('m')
                    ->where('(m.rights = :adminRight or m.rights = :managerRight) and m.user = :user')
                    ->setParameter('adminRight', RosterMember::ADMIN_LEVEL)
                    ->setParameter('managerRight', RosterMember::MANAGER_LEVEL)
                    ->setParameter('user', $user);
            },
            'required' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

As you can see I my QueryBuilder I use $user (the current user) as a parameter.
My controler looks like that:

```
public function createAction(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $alert = new RosterEvent;
    $alert->setEvent($event);

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RosterEventType(), $alert, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) { ....
```

My issue is that I need to pass the $user to the formbiulder. But I get "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::createForm() must be of the type array, object given,..." 
I know the problem is how I pass $user from the controller to the formbuilder. But I have no clue how to do that. 
Any ideas?

Comment: try passing the id of the user as follow: `$user->getId()`

Comment: try `->setParameter('user', $user->getId());`

Comment: Thanks @Matteo; I tried but I get Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::createForm() must be of the type array, integer given,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html), the third parameter (`$options = array()`) of method `createForm` need an array and not a object.

This line is wrong

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RosterEventType(), $alert, $user);
```

The `$options` parameter can be used for example like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('target_route'),
    'method' => 'GET',
));
```

**If you want pass a parameter to the form, you can try something like** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807388/passing-data-from-controller-to-type-symfony2)

*Controller*

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RosterEventType($user), $alert);
```

*Form*

```
protected $user;

public function __construct (User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, that the solution, I found it yesterday but thanks a lot. Also it is necessary to __construst the variable in the RosterEventType.php (as follows):      private $userId;

    public function __construct ($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter of createForm is expecting an array of options so use this when creating the form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RosterEventType(), $alert, array('user'=>$user));
```

Then you will need to get your RosterEventType to allow the 'user' option to be provided. You can do this by overriding the setDefaultOptions function of your AbstractType and provided a default value for the option. For example you can add the following to your RosterEventType class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'user' => false,
    ));
}
```

If you do this then you can access the user object in your buildForm function using $options['user'].

Comment: Well done ! ;)  Just for more information you can add in your post that the `setDefaultOptions ` was replaced by `configureOptions` in **Symfony 2.7**

Comment: Hi I accepted @zilongqiu answer as it is the same I am using but yours is also very good. Thanks a lot!!