# how to get doctrine repository in form type class in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ParabolaEntityBundle:ProjectAllocation');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.startDate < :sdate and p.employee = :emp and p.endDate > :edate')
                ->setParameter('sdate', date('Y-m-d', time()))
                ->setParameter('edate', date('Y-m-d', time()))
                ->setParameter('emp', $employee->getId())
                ->getQuery();
        $projectAllocate = $query->getResult();
```

how can i use above code in FormType class.I am using this query to generate array for the choice type  in form builder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `entity` type instead which has a `query_builder` option.

This link:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Describes how to do it.

If, for some reason you really don't want to use `entity` type, you could always retrieve data within controller and pass it via `FormType` constructor, which is a little bit quick 'n' dirty but should work just fine...

**Controller:**

```
$this->createForm(new MyFormType($results_from_qb), $form_data );
```

**FormType:**

```
public function __construct($results_from_qb){
    $this->results_from_qb = $results_from_qb; // store it into class member field to be used latter in buildForm method
}
```

Comment: In entity form type how to use nested query, because in my case i  have to get project entity base on projectallocation entity.

Comment: There is definitely a way to do it, could you just please explain me how those two entities are related? Uni/Bidirectional? Cardinality?

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I have a two entities that I do not want to use relationship between them. I found related questions and answers: [How to pass data to formBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder) and  [Passing data from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807388/passing-data-from-controller-to-type-symfony2)