# Symfony3 access doctrine in type object

Tags: php, symfony

How to get access to Doctrine object in type object in Symfony3?

In controller I could write for example:

```
$this->getDoctrine()
```

What should I write in object extends AbstractType ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Or how could I acces to database from Type object?

Comment: IMHO you are gonna use "AbstractType" in some controller and you can get doctrine service there. If this it not your case, then describe more specifically your use case

Comment: Define your types as a service and inject the entity manager as needed: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: @JanRydrych: I have many-to-many relationship. SomthingEntity and GeolocationEntity.
In SomethingForm I have text field to address, so I tried do geocode and write to DB in 
`addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) { 
// here
})`

Comment: @Cerad it works! Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get doctrine repository in form type class in symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714301/how-to-get-doctrine-repository-in-form-type-class-in-symfony2)