# Get many-to-many entities in a form properly

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm new with symfony, I looked around but I didn't find the right answer to my problem.

I have two entities linked with a many-to-many relation. Entity `User` -> Entity `FollowedUser`.
One `User` should be able to follow several `FollowedUser` and one `FollowedUser` should has several `Users` who follow him.

My problem is that when I try to list all `FollowedUser` for one `User`, say my `CurrentUser`, I get all `FollowedUser` not only those associated to my `CurrentUser`.

Here is my code.

**User Entity** (`src/MyBundle/Entity/User.php`) :

```php
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="My_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser

    // ...

    /**
     * @var FollowedUser[] $followedUsers 
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\FollowedUser")
     */
     private $followedUsers;

     // ...

     public function getFollowedUsers()
     {
         return $this->followedUsers;
     }
}
```

**UserType**:

```php
namespace MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use MyBundle\Entity\FollowedUserRepository;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {        
        $builder->add('followedUsers'); // This shows me the whole table
        //,'entity' , array('class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\FollowedUser',
        //                'multiple' => true,
        //                  'query_builder' => function(FollowedUserRepository $followedUserRepo) use ($options) {
        //                                         $followedUsers = $options['data']->getFollowedUsers();
        //                                         $choices = array();
        //                                         foreach ( $followedUsers as $followedUser){
        //                                             $choices[] = $followedUser->getId();
        //                                         }
        //                                         $qb = $followedUserRepo->createQueryBuilder('u');
        //                                         $qb->select('u')
        //                                            ->where( $qb->expr()->in('u.id',$choices));
        //                                         return $qb;
        //                                        }          
        //         ));
     }

    public function getName()
    {        
        return 'followedUser';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\User',
        );
    }
}
```

**NB:** The lines I commented is the only way I found to do what I want. But it does not feel the right way to do it.

In my Controller:

```php
$currentUser = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

$followedUsers = $currentUser->getFollowedUsers(); // That works properly

$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(),$currentUser);
```

**EDIT :**

Actually my problem was that I forgot some annotation in my ManyToMany declaration. Here is the default annotation which should be used for an unidirectionnal ManyToMany relation:

```php
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @JoinTable(name="users_groups",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

Solution was found in the doctrine documentation here : [doctrine2 unidirectionnal ManyToMany](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If specified, this is used to query the subset of options (and their
>   order) that should be used for the field. The value of this option can
>   either be a QueryBuilder object or a Closure. If using a Closure, it
>   should take a single argument, which is the EntityRepository of the
>   entity.

Without specifying `query_builder` Symfony 2  option you'll get all `FollowedUser`, as you said. The meaning of:

```
 $builder->add('followedUsers');
```

Is something like:

1. Add a field whose property is `followedUsers` of the `User` class.
2. Guess it's type (`entity` type).
3. `query_builder` option not specified? Then fetch **all users**.
4. Select (depending of `expanded` and `multiple` options) those (options) **users actually following the user from the model**, leaving all other (options) users unselected.

So, question for you is: why you want to display only the users following the user in the form model? It's a no sense... the actual user of the application will never be able to add new following users.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Actually I don't want the user to be able to add new following users. I want to display a unique `<select>` field with every followed users. Then when a following user is selected make an ajax request to grab info associated to this specific following user. Thx for the explanation I didn't understood this way but it makes sense as a form isn't usually made for display purpose. I have to use the `query_builder` then and pass my data through `$options['data']` or like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder) is it right?