# Symfony2 forms using FormBuilder: how to set fields from controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I want to create a form containing multiple forms using FormBuilder, each form corresponding to an entity. My problem is that I want to set some fields of the underlying forms from my controller.

The relations between my entities are:

- PollingStation OneToMany Candidate
- PollingStation OneToMany User
- Ballot ManyToOne Candidate
- Ballot ManyToOne PollingStation
- Ballot ManyToOne User

I have $pollingStation, $voter, and an array $candidates. I want each subform to refer to a different element of $candidates (for example, the voter evaluates each candidate individually).

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder), which gave me the idea to proceed as follows, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Controller:

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder();
$choices = $pollingStation->getCandidates();
foreach ($candidates as $candidate) 
{
    $ballotType = new BallotType($pollingStation, $voter, $candidate);
    $formBuilder->add($candidate->getName(), $ballotType);
}
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
```

BallotType:

```
public function __construct(\Entity\PollingStation $pollingStation, \Entity\User $user, \Entity\Candidate $candidate)
{
    $this->pollingStation = $pollingStation;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->candidate = $candidate;
}
```