# Symfony 2 forms - pass data to select without data class (no entity)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Suppose we have form in our controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new OurFormType());
```

Here is builder method of OurFormType class

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
     $builder
        ->add('list','choice')
        ->add('agency','text')
        ->add('type','hidden');
}
```

We have no data_class, no entity used at all. We can pass the data to the form using other way. The thing we interested in is **list** field, that has **choice** type. This type is used to create select list on symfony 2 forms.

Here we came to the task. And the task is to fill that **list** with data, that get in controller. Suppose it is associative array. So we can provide our modified controller action:

```
$listData = array('key1'=>'val1', 'key2' => 'val2');
$form = $this->createForm(new OurFormType());

return $this->render('UMDOurBundle:Test:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

I need to insert that array to the list field in my controller, after I pass object to $form variable.  Something like

```
$form->get('list',array('choices'=>$listData));
```

Is there something like that in symfony 2 forms?

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer on [Symfony 2 - how to pass data to formBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder) for the techinque to pass values to a FormType class using the constructor.