# How can I get ID of entity in form type?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have form type for build form of category:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('published', 'checkbox', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                ))
                ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'BWBlogBundle:Category',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->where('c.id != :id')
                                ->setParameter('id', ... /* I need to get category ID here */)
                            ;
                    },
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'Корневая категория',
                ))
            // other my code
```

How can I get category ID of entity in `query_builder` closure in `buildForm` action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer for your question into this two questions [symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder) and [passing-data-from-controller-to-type-symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807388/passing-data-from-controller-to-type-symfony2)

1) create `category` variable and `__construct()` method into `CategoryType` class:

```
private category;
public function __construct(yourBundle\Category $category){

   $this->category = $category ;

}
```

2) use category variable in `buildForm()` method into `CategoryType` class :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $category = $this->category;

    $builder
            ->add('published', 'checkbox', array(
                'required' => FALSE,
            ))
            ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'BWBlogBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($category){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                            ->where('c.id != :id')
                            ->setParameter('id', $category->getId())
                        ;
                },
                'required' => FALSE,
                'empty_value' => 'Корневая категория',
            ))

    }
```

**finally** when you create form in your controller :

```
$category = new Category();

$form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType($category),$category);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these answers are as valid now. If you have the following code to create a form in your controller:

```php
$fooEntity = $entityManager->find(FooEntity::class, 123);
$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class, $fooEntity);
```

... then the `MyFormType::buildForm()` method will be passed the `$options` parameter which will have `$options['data']` that contains the entity that you passed to createForm(), i.e., `$fooEntity` in this case. This is assuming you don't override the 'data' key option with your own value. So you should be able to get the entity's ID from that.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
  private $category_id;

  public function __construct($category_id=null) 
  {
    $this->category_id = $category_id;
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
        $builder
                ->add('published', 'checkbox', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                ))
                ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'BWBlogBundle:Category',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->where('c.id != :id')
                                ->setParameter('id', $this->category_id) /* I need to get category ID here */)
                            ;
                    },
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'Корневая категория',
                ))
            // other my code
   }
```

And when you create your form, do something like

```
public myFooController() 
{
  //retrieve %category_id here
  $form = $this->creteForm(new CategoryType($category_id));
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$options['data'] contains the entity for which the type is built.